# FPDF Error Cannot redeclare class FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I am receiving the following error when using FPDF

```
Cannot redeclare class FPDF in /home/www/etrackbureau.co.za/fpdf.php on line 12
```

I am not declaring other classes in any other section of the code

```
<?php
//include_once('diag.php');
include_once('mysql_table.php');
include_once('../../fpdf.php');


class PDF extends PDF_MySQL_Table
{
function Header()
{
    //Title
    $this->SetFont('Arial','',18);
    $this->Cell(0,6,'World populations',0,1,'C');
    $this->Ln(10);
    //Ensure table header is output
    parent::Header();
}
}

//Connect to database
mysql_connect('localhost','stingin_assist','trevor74');
mysql_select_db('stingin_assist');

$pdf=new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
//First table: put all columns automatically
$pdf->Table('select * from bureau order by rep_date');
$pdf->AddPage();
//Second table: specify 3 columns
$pdf->AddCol('rank',20,'','C');
$pdf->AddCol('name',40,'Country');
$pdf->AddCol('pop',40,'Pop (2001)','R');
$prop=array('HeaderColor'=>array(255,150,100),
            'color1'=>array(210,245,255),
            'color2'=>array(255,255,210),
            'padding'=>2);
$pdf->Table('select name, format(pop,0) as pop, rank from country order by rank limit 0,10',$prop);

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

I am declaring the class as far as I know only once. As I am new to FPDF a second question is this best to create PDF files with Graphs and writing in it. I have searched the forums and numerous has been mentioned. I am looking for a base line PDF system to write reports from information out of my DB and placing them into graphs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are combining several scripts from the FPDF website but each of them has this code somewhere at the top of the file:

```
require('fpdf.php');
```

For example, the code inside `diag.php` will require `sector.php` and that file will require `fpdf.php`. The code inside `mysql_table.php` will also require `fpdf.php`. This means `fpdf.php` is included more than once and thus the class FPDF is declared more than once, which results in the error you got. Change the line in all the files to:

```
require_once('fpdf.php');
```

The example scripts on the [FPDF website](http://fpdf.org/) show nicely what is possible. To actually combine the functionality of these different scripts, you might need to cut and paste functions from those scripts into one big class or change who `extends` what, to get multilevel (not multiple) inheritance.